# Problem with showing correct user_id link from array values in while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a social networking site where I want to  have a user's pals shown in a PHP generated table. I want to show pal thumbnails and other information below these thumbnails so that if you click on a thumbnail, it takes you to that user's profile.

My code:

```
<?php
//code for displaying all your pals
$query_pal_array = "SELECT pal_array FROM users WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
$pal_array_result = mysql_query($query_pal_array, $connections) or die(mysql_error());
$row_pal_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($pal_array_result);

$pal_array = $row_pal_array['pal_array'];

$palList = "";
if($pal_array !="")
{
    $palArray = explode(",",$pal_array);
    $palCount = count($palArray);   
}
else
{
    $palCount = "0";
}
//get pal avatars
$query_pal_info = "SELECT users.user_id, user_first_name, user_last_name, username, picture_thumb_url, avatar FROM users LEFT JOIN picture ON
users.user_id =  picture.user_id
AND picture.avatar=1 WHERE users.user_id IN ($pal_array)";
$pal_info = mysql_query($query_pal_info , $connections) or die(mysql_error());
$totalRows_pal_info = mysql_num_rows($pal_info );
echo $pal_array;

echo "\n<table>";
$j = 5;
while ($row_pal_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($pal_info))
{
    if($j==5) echo "\n\t<tr>";
    $thumbnail_user = $row_pal_info['picture_thumb_url'] != '' ? $row_pal_info['picture_thumb_url'] : '../Style/Images/default_avatar.png';
    echo "<td width='100' height='100' align='center' valign='middle'><a href = 'user_view.php?user_id2=$pal_array'>
    <img src='/NNL/User_Images/$thumbnail_user' border='0'/></a></td>\n";
    $j--;
    if($j==0) {
        echo "\n\t</tr>\n\t<tr>";
        $j = 5;
    } 
}
if($j!=5) echo "\n\t\t<td colspan=\"$j\"></td>\n\t</tr>";
echo "\n</table>";
?>
<table width="500" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td height="20"><div class="heading_text_18"><?php echo $row_user_info ['username']; ?>'s&nbsp;pals <?php echo $palCount ?></div>  </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="interactionLinksDiv" align="right" style="border:none;"><a href="#" onclick="return false" 
      onmousedown="javascript: toggleInteractContainers('pal_requests');">Pal Requests</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="5"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have user_id values stored in an array $pal_array. These are pal user_id numbers. When the thumbnails show, they all link to the last user_id in the array. What am I doing wrong. Im just learning PHP.

Comment: `I have user_id values stored in an array $pal_array. ` <- this. Is what you're doing wrong

Comment: ok, whats the way to fix it? When I echo $pal_array, I get 94,92 ie, user_id 94 and 92. The 2 thumbnails both link to user 94's profile.

Comment: store it in a table, not field.

Comment: Cheers, Col. Shrapnel , did some more research. I have a lot to fix. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Col. Shrapnel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874305/problem-with-showing-correct-user-id-link-from-array-values-in-while-loop#comment-5419306) stated, the first error is to store arrays as imploded strings instead of using the relational model and store the Pal entity in another user_user table.

The second error is to use an Array inside a String as in `WHERE users.user_id IN ($pal_array)`. You must implode it with commas first.

And the third error is that you can't use this:

```
echo "<td width='100' height='100' align='center' valign='middle'><a href = 'user_view.php?user_id2=$pal_array'>
<img src='/NNL/User_Images/$thumbnail_user' border='0'/></a></td>\n";
```

But this:

```
echo "<td width='100' height='100' align='center' valign='middle'><a href = 'user_view.php?user_id2={$row_pal_info['user_id']}'>
<img src='/NNL/User_Images/$thumbnail_user' border='0'/></a></td>\n";
```

This way, the ID will be different in each while loop.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Coquevas. For the first error, I have a table users with user_id, username etc and another field called pal_array that stores user_id's of pals separated by commas in the MySQl DB. What is the correct way to retrieve this information? I guess I'm not really getting it.I understand the second error. Ill try your third solution and tell you how it goes. I really appreciate

Comment: You can get more info about error #1 on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874305/problem-with-showing-correct-user-id-link-from-array-values-in-while-loop/4876551#4876551

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, you want the URLs of the thumbnail links to read something like this:

```
"user_view.php?user_id2=92"
"user_view.php?user_id2=93"
"user_view.php?user_id2=94"
"user_view.php?user_id2=95"
```

but from what I can tell, they're all using the value of the variable $pal_array, which, as far as I can tell looks like this

```
"92,93,94,95"
```

Which would make each and every one of your urls look like this:

```
"user_view.php?user_id2=92,93,94,95"
```

**The Fix:**
So to fix the immediate problem, you should explode() that list of ids and use those individually instead of the whole list at once. More important, however, is to set up your database correctly.

**The solution:**
Store your list of pals in a separate table, not in a field of the user. Each user has a number of pals. Each pal is another user with their own user Id. What you need is a separate table whose only job is to relate one user's ID to another's. Your two tables might look like this:

```
Table: User
    user_id int;
    username varchar;
    email varchar;
    thumbnail_url varchar;

Table: User_pals
    pal_1 int; //user_id of the first user
    pal_2 int; //user_id of pal of first user
    pals_confirmed bool; //False or 0 until both friends are in agreement
```

In this setup, the table User_pals is just a big 2 column list binding 2 users together (with an extra column to indicate if friendship has been confirmed). To get a given user's list of friends, you would simply do a couple of queries like this:

```
"SELECT pal_2 FROM User_pals WHERE pal_1 = $user_id";
"SELECT pal_1 FROM User_pals WHERE pal_2 = $user_id";
```

This would give you a nice list of user_ids that were pals of your user.
(There are more well designed table structure's than this that would require only one query, but you get the idea).

So hopefully this helps get you on the right track. More info can be found [at w3schools.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). Beyond that just googling around for relational database structure and design will be immensely useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jurassic_C. From your reply and others, I see why I have to restructure my database.